# HTML Form Action with DLL how to know which function

Tags: javascript, html, c++, forms, dll

So, I'm new to this stuff and I was wondering how can I debug/find which function needed to be fix if I have smtg like:

```
    <form name="frmAdmin" class="form-horizontal" method="post" 
action="/scripts/testing/Admin.dll" onSubmit="return checkValues();">
```

check value() just a javascript that return true / false depending if the textbox is empty or fill out

Now, when I click a submit button from that form it goes to another `page.htm`, I'm trying to change this so it goes to `page2.htm` instead. But I'm not sure how to fix this since the action goes to `Admin.dll`. I open `Admin.cpp`, but no idea what am I supposed looking at.

Comment: How do you expect people to answer this without knowing what Admin.dll does or how it functions. Providing a snippet of relevant code from Admin.cpp would be nice. Unfortunately I don't think even including that will make your question a good fit for SO.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I'm sorry my question is a bit broad. admin.cpp, is about 15,000 lines, so there's no way I put it in here. I think my main thing is, What function I need to look at Admin.cpp. I'm trying to understand, where the form action point to. I do some research but nothing really help.

Comment: I suggest you load up Dependency Walker and check out which functions Admin.dll exports and start from there. Chances are it only exports a few (maybe only one) if it's intended to be used by a particular server architecture. You should also refer to the docs for the web server you are using to determine what it's requirements  are for using DLL's in this manner (assuming a CGI like interface). From there you should be able to improve your question with this information.